# How to select query based on condition

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

In my database table I have

```
NAME   SCORE 
---------------
RAJ     GOLD   
MAYA    SILVER
RAJ     BRONZE
MAYA    GOLD
RAJ     SILVER
HARI    SILVER
```

In which the highest score in the order of `GOLD,SILVER,BRONZE`.

From this table I want to show the highest score of every person in a grid view.

The output should be:

```
NAME   SCORE 
----------------  
RAJ     GOLD  
MAYA    GOLD
HARI    SILVER
```

How is it possible? Through procedure, query or gridview row data bound ?

Comment: I suggest adding another scoring convention ( a numerical one instead of text) so that you need to write less code or save you a join if you do it differently. That way you could use built in functions like Max() rather than writing additional code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this to convert the strings to numbers and back again:

```
SELECT NAME, 
CASE WHEN MINSEQ=1 THEN 'GOLD'
     WHEN MINSEQ=2 THEN 'SILVER' 
     ELSE 'BRONZE'
END
FROM
(select NAME,
MIN(CASE WHEN SCORE='GOLD' THEN 1 WHEN SCORE='SILVER' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END) AS MINSEQ
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY NAME) AS T
```

A better solution will be to assign a number to each score in another table and join to that table.

```
SCORE  RANK
GOLD    1
SILVER  2
BRONZE  3
```

That way you don't have to hard code the conversion from score to rank.

Comment: Voted up for rankings table.